# Asp.net button to cycle through asp panels

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a number of panels on a webpage I am using sort of like a slideshow.
What is the best way to set up a single "Next", and "Previous" button to navigate through them, this will need to account for an unlimited amount of panels.

I am currently working in VB and the HTML is as follows on my bootstrap based site:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlInfo1" CssClass="col-lg-12" runat="server">
<div>
   <h3>Welcome</h3>
   <p>Text</p>
</div>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlInfo2" CssClass="col-lg-12" Visible="false" runat="server">
<div>
   <h3>Slide2</h3>
   <p>Slide 2 Text</p>
</div>
```

... And so on, ending finally with a button outside of the panels.

I've been reading through session variables as a means of keeping track of the current slide that is being used, but am still at a bit of a loss as to how to go about implementing it. Is this even a good way to go about creating a web based slideshow type page? Any tips/further reading would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Bob, you are showing Bootstrap as a tag. I have used the Bootstrap Carousel, so much easier then messing with the .NET panel. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: Sounds like you could use the asp.net Wizard Control

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen, Regency Software thank you both. Both of these seem to be quite useful for what i'm looking to achieve. I think i will concentrate more on trying to use the wizard control, will now just have to figure out how to style it. Thanks again.